# scala override keyword doesn't work

Tags: scala

I am writring a simple code to learn inheritance in Scala by overriding values from super class in sub class::

```
class point(xy: Int, ry: Int) {

  var x: Int = xy
  var y: Int = ry

    def move(dx: Int, dy: Int){

    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy

    println (x);
    println (y);

  }
}

class next(override val xy: Int, override val ry: Int, val tet: Int) extends point(xy,ry){ 
    var r: Int = tet

    def move(dx: Int, dy: Int, dz: Int ){

    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy
    r = r + tet

      println ("Point x location : " + x);
      println ("Point y location : " + y);
      println ("Point z location : " + r);
}
}

object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val loc = new next(10, 20, 15);

      // Move to a new location
      loc.move(10, 10, 5);
   }
}
```

I used the keyword "override" while extending my super class "point" in my subclass "next", but I am getting following errors::

```
    "value ry override nothing"
    "value xy override nothing"
```

But I am overriding them, but when I remove the keyword, the code has no error. Is there something missing from my code?

regards,Amitesh

Comment: I can assure that the `override` keyword in Scala most definitely *does* work. In general, if you think that a basic language feature that is used dozens of times of times each day by thousands of developers is broken, and *you are the first person ever to notice it*, you are usually wrong. While the Scala compiler is a complex beast, and it *does* have bugs, those bugs tend to be in much more obscure corners, usually in the type inferencer, type checker, or `implicit` resolver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your point class doesn't have `xy` or `ry` field/methods, so indeed you're not overriding anything. Use `class point(val xy: Int, val ry: Int)` if you want these constructor arguments to be turned into methods.